# Applying KVL to a circuit with only a battery and a capacitor

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage

My textbook states that KVL can be applied to a circuit with only a battery and a charging capacitor. According to the textbook then, the voltage across a capacitor always equals that of the battery. How is this possible?

Comment: Had you thought of joining our [electronics.se] stack for electrical/electronic-engineering questions?

Comment: What about this seems wrong to you? Remember, it's a textbook idealization. In the real world, additional details will matter. You could, of course, get a battery and a capacitor and see what happens.

Comment: @JohnDoty I can’t understand this because according to my knowledge, the potential difference across the capacitor equals the voltage of the battery once the capacitor has fully charged. The textbook states that this is true even during the charging process.

Comment: @Andromeda What determines how long the charging process takes?

Comment: You can infer from KVL that when any number of two-terminal components are connected in parallel with each other, then they must all see the same voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you model a battery as an ideal voltage source in series with an internal resistance then you have a standard RC circuit which charges the capacitor with a time constant of $\tau=RC$.

If you wish to consider a theoretical ideal voltage source then you can simply take the limit as $R$ goes to 0. In that hypothetical case the voltage source provides an infinite current for an infinitesimal time and the capacitor is fully charged with a time constant of 0.